# How to synchronize DateTime.Now with a NTP server?

Tags: c#, datetime, ntp

I have a NTP-Server and I am getting the date like below:

```
DateTime NTPDateTime = GetServerTime(); //GetServerTime returns a new DateTime
```

but my problem is, I only get the current time from ntp-server but cannot update it after without reconnecting to the NTP-Server.

I have tried to do it in a thread like (1000ms interval)

```
string displayTime() {
   this.lblServerTime.Text = NTPDateTime.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

It always shows the same DateTime as expected. Like (01.10.2014 - 15:31:25)

But how can I update the DateTime so that it always gives me the current DateTime?

Example if I use the following code, it gives me the current local time

```
//in a thread
string displayTime() {
   this.lblServerTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

But I need the server time and not localtime. and my problem is that I cannot get it everysecond.

is there a way to do it , without a new connection every second to the ntp-server? I have more then 500 client applications which needs server time.

Comment: You should configure your server to synchronize with the NTP server.

Comment: Are you wanting to set the *local system's* time, or just display the server's time? If you need server time, you will need to keep calling it.

Comment: Do you mean like synchronising the OS DateTime with the NTP server?

Comment: @crashmstr I need the servertime with seconds. and I want to do it without connecting to the NTP Server every second if it possible

Comment: what is `GetServerTime` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't without keeping polling it. The time on the server can change more or less than the local PC time, so you have to do a sync on every refresh.

Another option is to configure the PC to do a regular sync with the NTP server, and use the local time as the 'server time'.

You can't set `DateTime.Now` to the server time as you may want to.

The last option I can think of is to do a sync every minute or so, and keep the difference between local and server in memory, and adding it to the displayed time.

```
TimeSpan serverTimeDifference = GetServerTimeDifference();

DateTime actualTime = DateTime.Now + serverTimeDifference;
```

Where `GetServerTimeDifference` is:

```
private static TimeSpan GetServerTimeDifference()
{
    return GetServerTime() - DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: well this is better then sync. every second. Do you know about "Windows Time Service Tools and Settings" ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc773263(v=ws.10).aspx I have just found it now

Comment: Not aware of that. Could help if you have enough privileges.

Comment: I would like to upvote , but I cannot. I ll start with the idea, polling every minute from NTC-Server